# Linking multiple dropdown menus and removing/hiding duplicates

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have 4 dropdown menus in Excel that read off the same range.

I have used the dropdown menu found in 'data validation'.

I would like to remove/hide selections that have already been choosen in the other dropdown menus (i.e. the other 3). Of course if the user changes their mind about that certain choice, I would like the option/selection to reappear in each dropdown menu.

I have tried to Google this but I am not having a lot of luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having this sample:

[image]

With the Range for Validation Named DataVal1 (from E4:E10), use this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LstVal(1 To 10) As String
Dim Tmp(1 To 10)
Dim Coll As New Collection
Dim Vali As Integer
Dim i, x As Integer
Dim DropLst
Dim Dval
Dim xx
Dim SRange As String

SRange = "B4:B8"

Vali = 1
For Each DropLst In Range(SRange)
    Set Coll = Nothing
    For Each Dval In Range("DataVal1")
        Coll.Add Dval.Value
    Next

    For Each xx In Range(SRange)
        If DropLst.Address = xx.Address Then GoTo ENext
        For x = 1 To Coll.Count
            If Coll(x) = xx.Value Then
                Coll.Remove (x)
                GoTo ENext
             End If
        Next
ENext:
    Next

    Tmp(Vali) = ""
    For i = 1 To Coll.Count
        If (Tmp(Vali) <> "") Then Tmp(Vali) = Tmp(Vali) & "," & Coll(i)
        If (Tmp(Vali) = "") Then Tmp(Vali) = Tmp(Vali) & Coll(i)
    Next

    With DropLst.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Tmp(Vali)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Vali = Vali + 1
Next
End Sub
```

When you change the validation of one dropdown, the other are validate with a new Dynamic list.
With this code you can add how many Validation you want, changing the SRange range...
If you want the validation cell not near you need to cange a little the code...